# Bulk upsert (update or insert) of a stored procedure

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to do a bulk upsert (update or insert) in a stored procedure into a SQL Server database and I am using sequelizer to connecting the SQL Server database using Node js.

This is dataset is anywhere between 1-50k rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am trying this in nodejs using sequelizer

```
const upsertedData = [
  {
    id: "123",
    value: "Value 2"
  },
  {
    id: "124",
    value: "Value 1"
  }
]

const upsert = async (data) => {
  await sequelize.query(
    `BEGIN
      DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
      SET @json = :dataToBeUpserted
      MERGE INTO dbo.tableToBeUpserted AS Target
      USING (SELECT * from OpenJson(@json) WITH (
          id nvarchar(32),
          value nvarchar(32),
      )) AS Source
      ON (Target.id = Source.id)
      WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET 
          Target.value = Source.value
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN           
          INSERT (id, value)
          VALUES (Source.id, Source.value);
    END`,
    {
      replacements: {
        dataToBeUpserted: JSON.stringify(data)
      },
    }
  )
}
```

upsert(upsertedData)

However, I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

and I even tried in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'[
  {"id": 2, "info": {"name": "John", "surname": "Smith"}, "age": 25},
  {"id": 5, "info": {"name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith"}, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00"}
]';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (
    id INT 'strict $.id',
    firstName NVARCHAR(50) '$.info.name',
    lastName NVARCHAR(50) '$.info.surname',
    age INT,
    dateOfBirth DATETIME2 '$.dob'
  );
```

Getting this same error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with? What's the compatibility level of the database? (OpenJson requires a minimum of 130)

Comment: As said @ZoharPeled please check version: SELECT @@VERSION; SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = DB_NAME();

Comment: In addition to the above comments you also have too many commas in `value nvarchar(32),`

Comment: @ZoharPeled :i am using SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18330.0

Comment: That's the SSMS version, I'm asking about the server version. execute the queries AlexK have written in his comments to check

Answer (score 0):

Before SQL 2016 you can use XML format.

The equivalent of OPENJSON is [OPENXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You can also use JSON in SQL Server 2014, look the following articles:

[Consuming JSON Strings in SQL Server](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/)

[SQL Server JSON to Table and Table to JSON](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/sql-server-json-to-table-and-table-to-json/)

[Producing JSON Documents from SQL Server queries via TSQL](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/)

Comment: I didn't get any solution. because i am  using SQL 2014. I can't convert to XML, because i am trying to upload the XLSX and convert to JSON Array. but problem is OPENJSON is not supporting in SQL 2014

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Any news about it?

Comment: We moved our database from SQL 2014 to SQL 2017. So i am able to update/insert bulk records using OPENJSON. Thanks